# Difference between using IHttpHandler and webservice

Tags: ihttphandler

i need to understand when these two implementations used . what could be the motive of using one over other , can these be leveraged interchangeably.

Thanks in Advance
Dee

Answer (score 1):

An `IHttpHandler` is a "do it yourself" solution. You'll be handling everything yourself, and you'll be responsible for things like interoperability.

Using a web service (a WCF web service), you'll get serialization / deserialization, an infrastructure, and an ability for a client to easily consume your service.

For a "service"-type operation, use a web service. If your task doesn't fit that, then consider `IHttpHandler`.